# Error en angular 4: "property ... does not exist on type ..."

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Estoy comenzando con **angular4**, haciendo uso de la herramienta `angular-cli` he generado un proyecto de prueba y tengo un problema cuando intento usar el método de un servicio importado, este sería el código fuente:

### app/estudiante.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class EstudianteService {

  constructor() { }

  listar():string[] {
    return ["neder", "alfonso", "fandiño", "andrade"];
  }

}
```

### app/estudiante/estudiante.component.ts

```js
import { Component /* [, mas elementos...] */} from '@angular/core';
import { EstudianteService } from '../estudiante.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-estudiante',
  templateUrl: './estudiante.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./estudiante.component.css'],
  providers: [EstudianteService]
})
export class EstudianteComponent implements OnInit {

  lista:string[];
  /* Definiciones... */

  constructor(estudiante: EstudianteService) { 
    this.lista = estudiante.listar();
  }
  /* mas implementación... */

}
```

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error en la consola, no he podido determinar exactamente donde esta el problema.

[image: error]

He estado usando guiás de angular 2 basándome en sus aspectos similares y porque abunda mas información tales como:

- http://academia-binaria.com/angular2-di-inyeccion-de-dependencias/
- https://blog.enriqueoriol.com/2017/03/introduccion-angular-modulo-y-componente.html

Podrían asesorarme un poco con esto, la verdad estoy estudiando desde hoy me ha parecido muy bacano todo el tema de "divide y vencerás" para esta versión pero me estancado en este punto.

He intentado indicar el ámbito del método como publico

```js
public listar():string[] {
   return ["neder", "alfonso", "fandiño", "andrade"];
}
```

O al momento de llamarle, he incluso usar el termino `this` para asemejarlo a los ejemplos propuestos en las paginas de diferenciadas anteriormente, aunque estoy casi seguro que nada tiene que ver

```js
constructor(public estudiante: EstudianteService) { 
  this.lista = this.estudiante.listar();
}
```

Desde ya agradezco la colaboración ofrecida.

Comment: En el constructor (public estudiante: EstudianteService), y asegurate de tener el Servicio importado en el el app.module, ya que angular cli por defecto no te lo importa, solo crea el componente.

Comment: Prueba proveer el servicio en el módulo en vez del componente.